# Rally RestApi returns "NotAuthorized" AuthenticationState after call to AuthenticateWithApiKey

Tags: c#, rest, rally

I am getting inconsistent results with the following code:

```
RallyRestApi myRestApi = new RallyRestApi();
myRestApi.AuthenticateWithApiKey("<my_api_key>");
```

Most of the time, `myRestApi.AuthenticationState` is `RallyRestApi.AuthenticationResult.Authenticated` after the above code runs, and my application works great.  But occasionally, `myRestApi.AuthenticationState` is `RallyRestApi.AuthenticationResult.NotAuthorized` after the above code is run.  I have tried peering into the `myRestApi` properties, but nothing jumps out at me to investigate why the call to `AuthenticateWithApiKey` returns `NotAuthorized`.  Even if it did, what would be my solution to solve it so that I can authenticate reliably, every time?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass serverURI explicitly in authentication request, not rely on default one:

```
RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi();
restApi.AuthenticateWithApiKey("myApiKey", new Uri("https://rally1.rallydev.com"));
```

Comment: Thanks, @user2738882.  However, I'm curious why the serverURI needs set explicitly... why will the default rallyServer string not work?

Comment: does it help to you? If yes, please accept the answer.

Comment: It has so far, but as the original issue was intermittent, I cannot confirm 100% that this answer resolves the issue definitely.  Regardless, I'll mark this answer as accepted until it isn't ;)